# Custom Fields Value As Taxonomy

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I creating a real estate platform where allow users to add their listing. The users are people who may not know how to using wp platform, so I make it as easy as possible for them to make a post. Thanks for the custom post type, I manage to create a post type that specifically for add listing. In this post type, there are many custom fields to store the necessary information like location, property type and etc...

Since I make it simple to use, so I didn't use the categories to sort the posts. However, what I like to do is let the custom field values as the taxonomies. For example:

**[States] <- this is custom field in select/radio type**

- [state 1] <- this is custom field value option for states
- [state 2] <- this is custom field value option for states
- [state 3] <- this is custom field value option for states
- [state 4] <- this is custom field value option for states
- [etc...] <- this is custom field value option for states

So I want to sort the posts according to the value in State that user selected. My idea is to make each of the value [[state 1],[state 2],[state 3]...] to be the categories. When the user select the option, it will automatically become the categories of the post. Possible to do this?

Comment: Close-voted as **too localized**. You're basically asking, "*how can I use a custom field as a custom taxonomy, because I don't want to use custom taxonomies?*"

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, WP has a build in function to attach a custom taxonomy to a (custom) posttype: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: Nope, what I know is register_taxonomy is insert the taxonomy in writing panel then let the user to tick or select. What I want is assign the custom meta values (from custom field) become the taxonomies. Not create a new taxonomy panel.

Comment: Why does it have to be a custom field? A taxonomy is looks perfect for this.

Comment: Well, I using the custom field at the first place, so it would be easier if stick with it. If there are no other wyas to make it, then I will change to taxonomy eventually. Anyway,thanks for your advice.

Comment: Maybe the problem with a taxonomy is that the user is able to "Add new" and there's the "Most used" feature...

Answer (score 0):

One possible option (don't think I fully understand) is to use [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) with their [Category](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/categories-field/) add-on field (which would allow you to save the categories as a custom field AND as the actual taxonomy for the post - still don't completely understand the use-case, but that would seem to fit your requirements.

Comment: There is no options to add new term for ACF category addon. If field type is `taxanomy`, you can not add new values for that, like it is on defoult wordpress taxanomy block. I also need this function.